# Javafx application on Windows without Java ( Maven or ...?)

Tags: java, maven, javafx-8

I have made an application in JavaFx. Is it possible to quickly converted into maven and attach java so you could run the application on a system Windows without installed Java. Or is there some other way to solve this problem? I am seeking advice on this topic. This is my work in college, but not studying computer science and professor wants to see the end result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oracle released the [javapackager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/javapackager.html) tool as part of the JDK, which can embed a JRE.

Tutorial: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/self-contained-packaging.html#BCGIBBCI

JavaFX Ant Tasks: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/javafx_ant_tasks.html#CHDBGIJG

AFAIK, the Maven JavaFX Plugin supports embedding JREs as well: https://github.com/javafx-maven-plugin/javafx-maven-plugin

Comment: When using Gradle as build-tool, you can even use the [javafx-gradle-plugin](https://github.com/FibreFoX/javafx-gradle-plugin) :D (disclaimer: I'm the maintainer of the javafx-maven-plugin and the creator of the javafx-gradle-plugin)

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried it for a while but have a look at [JSmooth](http://jsmooth.sourceforge.net/)

It enables you to create an executable that contains the JRE. (By using a  GUI)

From the site

> It creates native Windows launchers (standard .exe) for your java applications. It makes java deployment much smoother and user-friendly, as it is able to find any installed Java VM by itself.

and

> Sometimes it's more convenient to bundle a JRE with your application.
>   JSmooth can deal with that too...

You can download the latest (which has not been maintained for a while now) [here.](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jsmooth/files/jsmooth/0.9.9-7/)